# F# Trying to write HTTP response to TCP stream

Tags: http, tcp, f#

I'm trying to make a simple HTTP server in F#. But unfortunately I'm stuck at the response stage, I'm trying to create a simple 404 response but my browser won't get it, it will simply load and load the page forever not going anywhere. I can't figure out where my code could be wrong.

```
let responseString = "HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND";
let buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);

let processRequest (client: TcpClient)  = 
    async {  do printfn "Incoming HTTP request..."
             use stream = client.GetStream()
             use sr = new StreamReader(stream)
             let! content = sr.ReadToEndAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
             do 
                printfn "Stream contains:\n%s" content 
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) 
                stream.Flush() }

let ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")
let listener = TcpListener(ip, 8080)
let startServer = 
    async { do listener.Start() 
            do printfn "Starting server..."
            while true do 
                let! context = listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
                do! processRequest context }

Async.Start startServer
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code using the debugger?

Comment: Have you tried reading the standard or at least looking into some working examples? This is not HTTP what you are doing (no proper line ends, no end of header).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, I have read many working examples but almost all of them use the `HttpListener` class which will do most of this for me.

Comment: If you want to implement HTTP by yourself then you better read the [standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt). But I gave a few hints in my first comment on what is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the TCP stream does not know when the client has sent all its data (unless you e.g. close the browser), so the StreamReader is blocked forever.
If you want to implement HTTP by yourself, you'd need (for starters) to read line by line and check whether the client is allowed to send any more data.

Comment: Oh okay so it is actually the reading that is the problem here then? That explains a few things. So I'd have to go and read the specs on HTTP requests then?

Answer (score 1):

As @CaringDev points out, ReadToEnd doesn't terminate. That said for a simple HTTP server you'd only need to read the first line of the request. Here's an updated version of your code that reads the first line only and responds with a 200 OK:

```
open System.Net

let processRequest (client: Sockets.TcpClient) = async {  
  printfn "Incoming HTTP request..."
  use stream = client.GetStream()
  use sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
  let line = sr.ReadLine()
  printfn "Request: %s" line
  let sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream)
  sw.WriteLine("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nHello World")
  sw.Flush()     
  }

let ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")
let listener = Sockets.TcpListener(ip, 8080)
let startServer = async { 
  do listener.Start() 
  do printfn "Starting server..."
  while true do 
    let! context = listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
    processRequest context |> Async.Start
  }

Async.Start startServer
```

I'd also be tempted to change `do! processRequest context` to `processRequest context |> Async.Start` so that you can process multiple requests simultaneously.